# Trocar cor do texto por sorteio

Tags: jquery

Pessoal eu tenho um array com 4 cores gostaria de sortear uma cor a cada 4 segundos e trocar a cor da fonte de um H1 que tenho na pagina e para isto usar o fadein e fadeout como transição. Obrigado

Comment: João, acho que a resposta é a mesma que a pergunta que referí, no teu caso só tens de mudar no `.css()` para `$("h1").css("color", selectedcolor); `

Comment: @renan quando marquei como duplicada é tipo martelo, fecha logo. Desculpa se estavas a escrever uma resposta. Mas é duplicada mesmo não é?

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigado pela ajuda.